# Apple Mach-O Linker Error and I don't know why

Tags: ios, objective-c, linker-errors

I am making a simple game and have ran into a problem.
I am getting this error:

duplicate symbol _vertices in:
    /Users/--/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WorkingTitle_skeleton-gcgtpewqagbzyxbauptoayplozbs/Build/Intermediates/WorkingTitle skeleton.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/WorkingTitle skeleton.build/Objects-normal/i386/ViewController.o
    /Users/--/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WorkingTitle_skeleton-gcgtpewqagbzyxbauptoayplozbs/Build/Intermediates/WorkingTitle skeleton.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/WorkingTitle skeleton.build/Objects-normal/i386/Block.o
duplicate symbol _indices in:
    /Users/--/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WorkingTitle_skeleton-gcgtpewqagbzyxbauptoayplozbs/Build/Intermediates/WorkingTitle skeleton.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/WorkingTitle skeleton.build/Objects-normal/i386/ViewController.o
    /Users/--/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WorkingTitle_skeleton-gcgtpewqagbzyxbauptoayplozbs/Build/Intermediates/WorkingTitle skeleton.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/WorkingTitle skeleton.build/Objects-normal/i386/Block.o
ld: 2 duplicate symbols for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I have tried starting a new project and trying it again, but nothing has worked yet.
I have a C++ background and kinda just jumped into Objective-C, so that might be it.

Here is my code:

ViewController.m:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController () {
    Block *testBlock;
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) EAGLContext *context;

- (void)setupGL;
- (void)teardownGL;
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.context = [[EAGLContext alloc] initWithAPI:kEAGLRenderingAPIOpenGLES2];

    GLKView *view = (GLKView *)self.view;
    view.context = self.context;
    view.drawableMultisample = GLKViewDrawableMultisample4X;
    view.drawableStencilFormat = GLKViewDrawableStencilFormatNone;
    view.drawableColorFormat = GLKViewDrawableColorFormatRGBA8888;
    view.drawableDepthFormat = GLKViewDrawableDepthFormat24;

    [EAGLContext setCurrentContext:self.context];

    self.preferredFramesPerSecond = 60;
    self.pauseOnWillResignActive = YES;
    self.resumeOnDidBecomeActive = NO;

    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTapGesture:)];
    tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];

    [self setupGL];
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [self teardownGL];

    if ([EAGLContext currentContext] == self.context)
        [EAGLContext setCurrentContext:nil];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    if ([self isViewLoaded] && ([[self view] window] == nil))
        self.view = nil;

    [self teardownGL];

    if ([EAGLContext currentContext] == self.context)
        [EAGLContext setCurrentContext:nil];

    self.context = nil;

    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void)setupGL
{
    [EAGLContext setCurrentContext:self.context];

    testBlock = [[Block alloc] initWithType:BT_STONE andAccessory:BA_NONE];

}

- (void)teardownGL
{
    [EAGLContext setCurrentContext:self.context];

    [testBlock tearDown];
}

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    self.paused = !self.paused;
}

- (void)handleTapGesture:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender {
    if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateRecognized) {

    }
}

#pragma mark - GLKView and GLKViewController delegate methods

- (void)update
{
    aspect = fabsf(self.view.bounds.size.width / self.view.bounds.size.height);
    timeSinceLastUpdate = self.timeSinceLastUpdate;
    [testBlock update];
}

- (void)glkView:(GLKView *)view drawInRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    [testBlock draw];
}

@end
```

Defines.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <GLKit/GLKit.h>


enum BlockType {
    BT_NONE,
    BT_AIR,
    BT_GRASS,
    BT_DIRT,
    BT_STONE,
    BT_WATER,
    BT_SNOW,
    BT_WOOD,
    BT_LEAVES,
    BT_SAND,
    BT_GRAVEL
};

enum BlockAccessory {
    BA_NONE,
    BA_LADDER,
    BA_SNOW
};

enum Biome {
    BI_SNOWY,
    BI_PLAINS,
    BI_BEACH,
    BI_DESERT,
    BI_FOREST,
    BI_SAVANNA,
};

typedef enum BlockType BlockType;
typedef enum BlockAccessory BlockAccessory;
typedef enum Biome Biome;

typedef struct
{
    GLKVector3 positionCoordinates;
    GLKVector4 colorRGBA;
    GLKVector2 textCoord;
    GLKVector3 vertNorm;
} VertexData;

float aspect;
NSTimeInterval timeSinceLastUpdate;

VertexData vertices[] = {
    // Front
    {{1, -1, 1}, {1, 0, 0, 1}, {1, 0}, {0, 0, 1}},
    {{1, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 0, 1}, {1, 1}, {0, 0, 1}},
    {{-1, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 1, 1}, {0, 1}, {0, 0, 1}},
    {{-1, -1, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}},
    // Back
    {{1, 1, -1}, {1, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 1}, {0, 0, -1}},
    {{-1, -1, -1}, {0, 1, 0, 1}, {1, 0}, {0, 0, -1}},
    {{1, -1, -1}, {0, 0, 1, 1}, {0, 0}, {0, 0, -1}},
    {{-1, 1, -1}, {0, 0, 0, 1}, {1, 1}, {0, 0, -1}},
    // Left
    {{-1, -1, 1}, {1, 0, 0, 1}, {1, 0}, {-1, 0, 0}},
    {{-1, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 0, 1}, {1, 1}, {-1, 0, 0}},
    {{-1, 1, -1}, {0, 0, 1, 1}, {0, 1}, {-1, 0, 0}},
    {{-1, -1, -1}, {0, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 0}, {-1, 0, 0}},
    // Right
    {{1, -1, -1}, {1, 0, 0, 1}, {1, 0}, {1, 0, 0}},
    {{1, 1, -1}, {0, 1, 0, 1}, {1, 1}, {1, 0, 0}},
    {{1, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 1, 1}, {0, 1}, {1, 0, 0}},
    {{1, -1, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}},
    // Top
    {{1, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 0, 1}, {1, 0}, {0, 1, 0}},
    {{1, 1, -1}, {0, 1, 0, 1}, {1, 1}, {0, 1, 0}},
    {{-1, 1, -1}, {0, 0, 1, 1}, {0, 1}, {0, 1, 0}},
    {{-1, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}},
    // Bottom
    {{1, -1, -1}, {1, 0, 0, 1}, {1, 0}, {0, -1, 0}},
    {{1, -1, 1}, {0, 1, 0, 1}, {1, 1}, {0, -1, 0}},
    {{-1, -1, 1}, {0, 0, 1, 1}, {0, 1}, {0, -1, 0}},
    {{-1, -1, -1}, {0, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 0}, {0, -1, 0}}
};

GLubyte indices[] = {
    0, 1, 2,
    2, 3, 0,
    // Back
    4, 6, 5,
    4, 5, 7,
    // Left
    8, 9, 10,
    10, 11, 8,
    // Right
    12, 13, 14,
    14, 15, 12,
    // Top
    16, 17, 18,
    18, 19, 16,
    // Bottom
    20, 21, 22,
    22, 23, 20
};
```

Block.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "Defines.h"

@interface Block : NSObject
{

}

- (id)init;
- (id)initWithType:(BlockType)blockTypee andAccessory:(BlockAccessory)blockAccessorye;
- (void)setupEverythingElse;
- (void)setupVBOs;
- (void)draw;
- (void)update;
- (void)tearDown;

@end
```

Block.m:

```
#import "Block.h"

@interface Block ()
{
    BlockType blockType;
    BlockAccessory blockAccessory;
    GLuint _vertexBuffer;
    GLuint _indexBuffer;
    GLuint _vertexArray;
    float _rotation;
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) GLKBaseEffect *effect;

@end

@implementation Block

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        blockType = BT_NONE;
        blockAccessory = BA_NONE;
    }

    return self;
}

- (id)initWithType:(BlockType)blockTypee andAccessory:(BlockAccessory)blockAccessorye
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        blockType = blockTypee;
        blockAccessory = blockAccessorye;
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [self tearDown];
}

- (void)tearDown
{
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &_vertexBuffer);
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &_indexBuffer);

    self.effect = nil;
}

- (void)setupEverythingElse
{
    glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);

    self.effect = [[GLKBaseEffect alloc] init];
    self.effect.colorMaterialEnabled = NO;

    NSDictionary *options = @{GLKTextureLoaderOriginBottomLeft: @YES};
    NSError *error;
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"tile_floor" ofType:@"png"];
    GLKTextureInfo *info = [GLKTextureLoader textureWithContentsOfFile:path options:options error:&error];
    if (info == nil)
        NSLog(@"Error loading file: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    self.effect.texture2d0.name = info.name;
    self.effect.texture2d0.enabled = true;
    // Setup texture 2 if necessary (like a ladder on this block)

    [self setupVBOs];
}

- (void)setupVBOs
{
    glGenVertexArraysOES(1, &_vertexArray);
    glBindVertexArrayOES(_vertexArray);

    glGenBuffers(1, &_vertexBuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _vertexBuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glGenBuffers(1, &_indexBuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, _indexBuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(indices), indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribPosition);
    glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribPosition, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(VertexData), (const GLvoid*) offsetof(VertexData, positionCoordinates));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribColor);
    glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribColor, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(VertexData), (const GLvoid*) offsetof(VertexData, colorRGBA));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribTexCoord0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribTexCoord0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(VertexData), (const GLvoid*) offsetof(VertexData, textCoord));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribNormal);
    glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribNormal, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(VertexData), (const GLvoid*) offsetof(VertexData, vertNorm));

    glBindVertexArrayOES(0);
}

- (void)draw
{
    [self.effect prepareToDraw];
    glBindVertexArrayOES(_vertexArray);
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, (sizeof(indices) / sizeof(indices[0])), GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);

    // Draw VertexData array
}

- (void)update
{
    // Setup texture 2 if necessary (like a ladder on this block)

    GLKMatrix4 projectionMatrix = GLKMatrix4MakePerspective(GLKMathDegreesToRadians(65.0f), aspect, 4.0f, 10.0f);
    self.effect.transform.projectionMatrix = projectionMatrix;

    GLKMatrix4 modelViewMatrix = GLKMatrix4MakeTranslation(0.0f, 0.0f, -6.0f);
    _rotation = 90 * timeSinceLastUpdate;
    modelViewMatrix = GLKMatrix4Rotate(modelViewMatrix, GLKMathDegreesToRadians(25), 1, 0, 0);
    modelViewMatrix = GLKMatrix4Rotate(modelViewMatrix, GLKMathDegreesToRadians(_rotation), 0, 1, 0);
    self.effect.transform.modelviewMatrix = modelViewMatrix;
}

@end
```

Sorry for this being so long.  Thanks for reading all of it, or as much as you needed to. Please tell me if you need more details.

Comment: The key is probably in the error message.  You quoted "2 duplicate symbols" but didn't say what they were or which files they were found in.  It's good to give exact error messages instead of trying to describe them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your "defines.h" file includes actual symbol definitions, not just declarations, for `vertices` and `indices`.  Any attempt to import/include that file in multiple compilation units will cause duplicate symbols.

You need to move the actual code generating portion into an implementation file instead of a header.

Answer (score 5):

You would have forgotten to add the required `Frameworks`

Find the frameworks you need to import and add it, as it is in the screenshots

The missed framework might be `OpenGLES.framework` try to add it as it is in the images below

See the images below [image: Screenshot 1]

[image: ScreenShot 2]

If you still have any doubts about adding frameworks, continue to the [link](http://code-and-coffee.blogspot.in/2012/09/how-to-add-frameworks-in-xcode-4.html)

Comment: I already have: OpenGLES, UIKit, GLKit, Foundation, CoreGraphics, and QuartzCore.